# How to share models between applications?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

my application model contains  three fields. The first one will be shared with mail application as the mail destination ; the second one will be shared  with aps application as the frequency of the graph shown thank to the page index.html .
I think I'm quite close but  when I write in the terminal the command "runserver" it shows the error below :

> "needs updating." % name django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
>   Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the
>   'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form ConfigurationFrorm needs
>   updating.

Here is my code , any ideas what I am doing wrong ??

project/choix/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from choix.forms import ConfigurationForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from choix.models import Configuration 
from django import forms 
class Meta:
        model = Configuration
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' :
        form = ConfigurationForm()
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form 

        return render_to_response('create_article.html', args)
    else:
        form = ConfigurationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            e_mail = form.e_mail.data['e_mail']
            temps = form.temps.data['temps']
            temperature = form.temperature.data['temperature']
            post = m.Post.objects.create(e_mail=e_mail,
                                                         temps=temps, temperature = temperature)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'post_id' : post.id}))


    return render(request, 'choix/configuration.html',  {'form': form})
```

project/aps/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rasp import foo
from choix import views 
from choix.forms import ConfigurationForm
from django import forms
from choix.models import Configuration 

import json 


class ConfigurationFrorm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
        model = Configuration
def index(request,self):
    cleaned_data = super(ConfigurationForm, self).clean()
    temps = cleaned_data.get("temps")

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'t' : foo(), 'form':form, 'f':temps})
```

project/mail/views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from choix import views 
from choix.forms import ConfigurationForm
from django import forms 
from choix.models import Configuration 

class ConfigurationFrorm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
        model = Configuration
def index(request,self):

    subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'subject')
    message = request.POST.get('message', 'attention ! la temperature a depasse le maximum ')
    from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', 'jkhgyfydfth@gmail.com')
    cleaned_data = super(ConfigurationForm, self).clean()
    to  = cleaned_data.get("email")
    if subject and message and from_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [ to ])
            return HttpResponse('templates/mail.html')
        except BadHeaderError:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('mail')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

Comment: Did you try updating ContentForm?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, as of Django 1.8 you need to explicitly tell `ConfigurationForm` which model fields you want to include, using either the `fields` or `exclude` class attribute. If you want all of the fields, you can simply say `fields = '__all__'`. Django no longer assumes that automatically.

There are several indentation and spelling errors in the code you posted, which make it hard to follow. The best way to avoid that is to copy and paste your actual code rather than typing it in.

Comment: I copied and posted it.and I have writen fields = '__all_'  in my forms.py

Comment: You didn't say what happened. (I'm assuming you including a double underscore at the end of all: `fields = '__all__'`. If you're getting the same message, please edit your question to show your current code for ConfigurationForm. That's what I meant by copying and pasting: the code in your question needs to be accurate.